# SQL select with multiple counts from the same column

Tags: sql, database, select, count

I have one table in SQL with the following columns: Status, CreateDateTime and Case Type

Example of 10 rows of data looks like the following:

```
    Resolved-Withdrawn  2017-08-28 10:20:58.820 Termination Quote DE
    Pending-Customer    2017-08-28 10:44:37.987 Termination Quote DE
    Pending-Customer    2017-08-28 10:44:39.953 Termination Quote DE 
    Pending-Customer    2017-08-28 10:51:55.643 Termination Quote DE
    Pending-Customer    2017-08-28 10:51:56.513 Termination Quote DE
    Pending-Customer    2017-08-28 10:54:20.160 Termination Quote DE
    Pending-Customer    2017-08-28 10:54:20.747 Termination Quote DE
    Pending-Customer    2017-09-10 06:12:52.113 Termination Quote DE
    Pending-Customer    2017-09-15 12:34:32.657 Termination Quote DE
```

I would like to achieve the following:

```
    Status               Total_August     Total_September
    -----------------------------------------------------
    Resolved-Withdrawn   1                0
    Pending-Customer     6                2
```

How would I create this query within SQL?

My initial idea would be something like this (which obviously doesn't work), but maybe it gives you a better understanding of my thought process as a non-experience user.

```
    SELECT Status, COUNT(pxCreateDateTime) as Total_August, COUNT(pxCreateDateTime) as Total_September
    FROM ContractMgtWork
    WHERE  MONTH(pxCreateDateTime) = 8 and YEAR(pxCreateDateTime) = 2017 AND 
    CaseType = 'Amortization Schedule DE'
    GROUP BY Status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count`, like many other aggregate functions, skips `null`s. You can utilize this property by counting a `case` expression with whatever your want to count:

```
SELECT   Status, 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(pxCreateDateTime) = 8 THEN 1 END) AS Total_August,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(pxCreateDateTime) = 9 THEN 1 END) AS Total_September
FROM     ContractMgtWork
WHERE    YEAR(pxCreateDateTime) = 2017 AND 
         CaseType = 'Amortization Schedule DE'
GROUP BY Status
```